# Why are these tables different sizes, even though they are otherwise identical?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have exported my tables from STATA using esttab, 3 of the 4 of my tables are the same size, however, one of them seems to be smaller, even though they all have the same number of elements, the only thing that differs is the numbers contained within.

```
\begin{table}[h]

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table B2}
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.8}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.9}\\
\midrule
dsentiment      &  -0.0906\sym{*}  &  -0.0929         &  -0.0923\sym{*}  &  -0.0912\sym{**} &  -0.0908\sym{**} &  -0.0904\sym{*}  &  -0.0892         &  -0.0881         \\
                & (0.0358)         & (0.0552)         & (0.0448)         & (0.0340)         & (0.0338)         & (0.0364)         & (0.0539)         & (0.0751)         \\
\addlinespace
dsubmissions    &   0.0445\sym{***}&   0.0208         &   0.0272\sym{*}  &   0.0380\sym{***}&   0.0432\sym{***}&   0.0475\sym{***}&   0.0603\sym{***}&   0.0717\sym{***}\\
                &(0.00985)         & (0.0152)         & (0.0124)         &(0.00947)         &(0.00940)         & (0.0101)         & (0.0150)         & (0.0208)         \\
\addlinespace
lag\_vol         &    0.616\sym{***}&    0.658\sym{***}&    0.647\sym{***}&    0.628\sym{***}&    0.619\sym{***}&    0.611\sym{***}&    0.589\sym{***}&    0.569\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0459)         & (0.0822)         & (0.0668)         & (0.0508)         & (0.0505)         & (0.0543)         & (0.0804)         &  (0.112)         \\
\addlinespace
stdev\_lag       &   -3.251\sym{*}  &   -4.558         &   -4.203\sym{*}  &   -3.608\sym{*}  &   -3.320\sym{*}  &   -3.084         &   -2.380         &   -1.749         \\
                &  (1.468)         &  (2.525)         &  (2.052)         &  (1.559)         &  (1.549)         &  (1.667)         &  (2.468)         &  (3.438)         \\
\addlinespace
autocov         &   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0971\sym{***}&   0.0972\sym{***}&   0.0972\sym{***}&   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0974\sym{***}&   0.0975\sym{**} \\
                & (0.0166)         & (0.0259)         & (0.0210)         & (0.0160)         & (0.0159)         & (0.0171)         & (0.0253)         & (0.0352)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant        &    8.189\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
                &  (0.946)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
\midrule
Observations    &      459         &      459         &      459         &      459         &      459         &      459         &      459         &      459         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\

\end{tabular}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table B3}
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.6}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.8}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.9}\\
\midrule
dsentiment      &   -0.343\sym{***}&  -0.0907         &   -0.167         &   -0.271         &   -0.317\sym{*}  &   -0.364\sym{*}  &   -0.488\sym{***}&   -0.637\sym{**} \\
                & (0.0861)         &  (0.306)         &  (0.252)         &  (0.185)         &  (0.161)         &  (0.143)         &  (0.143)         &  (0.226)         \\
\addlinespace
dsubmissions    &    0.150\sym{***}&   0.0664         &   0.0917         &    0.126\sym{**} &    0.142\sym{***}&    0.157\sym{***}&    0.198\sym{***}&    0.248\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0190)         & (0.0693)         & (0.0571)         & (0.0420)         & (0.0366)         & (0.0327)         & (0.0332)         & (0.0537)         \\
\addlinespace
lag\_vol         &    0.886\sym{***}&    0.837\sym{***}&    0.852\sym{***}&    0.872\sym{***}&    0.882\sym{***}&    0.891\sym{***}&    0.915\sym{***}&    0.944\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0283)         &  (0.133)         &  (0.109)         & (0.0802)         & (0.0696)         & (0.0617)         & (0.0614)         & (0.0948)         \\
\addlinespace
stdev\_lag       &   -1.210\sym{***}&   -1.669         &   -1.531         &   -1.341         &   -1.256         &   -1.171         &   -0.944         &   -0.673         \\
                &  (0.346)         &  (2.238)         &  (1.837)         &  (1.346)         &  (1.168)         &  (1.036)         &  (1.028)         &  (1.582)         \\
\addlinespace
autocov         &    0.178\sym{***}&    0.211         &    0.201         &    0.187         &    0.181\sym{*}  &    0.175\sym{*}  &    0.159\sym{*}  &    0.140         \\
                & (0.0375)         &  (0.169)         &  (0.139)         &  (0.102)         & (0.0882)         & (0.0782)         & (0.0776)         &  (0.119)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant        &    2.273\sym{***}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
                &  (0.537)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
\midrule
Observations    &      345         &      345         &      345         &      345         &      345         &      345         &      345         &      345         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

[image: Table 4 being smaller than table 5]

I would appreciate some help in making them the same size, thank you

Comment: you have `\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}`  a `c` column has no specified width it is as wide as the data contained in the column so different tables will be different widths

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two main suggestions.

- In the case of your tables, it would seem desirable not to center-set the numbers in the 8 data columns but to align them on their decimal markers. This may be done by loading the `dcolumn` package and employing the package's `D` column type. As a side-effect of making this change, the data columns will also line up across the tables.
- To make sure that both tables fit inside the textblock, I suggest you replace the `tabular` environments with `tabular*` environments, with widths set to `\textwidth` (and with `\tabcolsep` set to `0pt`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set the page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column whitespace amounts

\caption{Table B2\strut}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{d{2.6}} }
\toprule
&\mc{OLS}&\mc{0.1}&\mc{0.2}&\mc{0.4}&\mc{0.5}&\mc{0.6}&\mc{0.8}&\mc{0.9}\\
\midrule
dsentiment      &  -0.0906\sym{*}  &  -0.0929         &  -0.0923\sym{*}  &  -0.0912\sym{**} &  -0.0908\sym{**} &  -0.0904\sym{*}  &  -0.0892         &  -0.0881         \\
                & (0.0358)         & (0.0552)         & (0.0448)         & (0.0340)         & (0.0338)         & (0.0364)         & (0.0539)         & (0.0751)         \\
\addlinespace
dsubmissions    &   0.0445\sym{***}&   0.0208         &   0.0272\sym{*}  &   0.0380\sym{***}&   0.0432\sym{***}&   0.0475\sym{***}&   0.0603\sym{***}&   0.0717\sym{***}\\
                &(0.00985)         & (0.0152)         & (0.0124)         &(0.00947)         &(0.00940)         & (0.0101)         & (0.0150)         & (0.0208)         \\
\addlinespace
lag\_vol         &    0.616\sym{***}&    0.658\sym{***}&    0.647\sym{***}&    0.628\sym{***}&    0.619\sym{***}&    0.611\sym{***}&    0.589\sym{***}&    0.569\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0459)         & (0.0822)         & (0.0668)         & (0.0508)         & (0.0505)         & (0.0543)         & (0.0804)         &  (0.112)         \\
\addlinespace
stdev\_lag       &   -3.251\sym{*}  &   -4.558         &   -4.203\sym{*}  &   -3.608\sym{*}  &   -3.320\sym{*}  &   -3.084         &   -2.380         &   -1.749         \\
                &  (1.468)         &  (2.525)         &  (2.052)         &  (1.559)         &  (1.549)         &  (1.667)         &  (2.468)         &  (3.438)         \\
\addlinespace
autocov         &   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0971\sym{***}&   0.0972\sym{***}&   0.0972\sym{***}&   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0973\sym{***}&   0.0974\sym{***}&   0.0975\sym{**} \\
                & (0.0166)         & (0.0259)         & (0.0210)         & (0.0160)         & (0.0159)         & (0.0171)         & (0.0253)         & (0.0352)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant        &    8.189\sym{***} \\
                &  (0.946)          \\
\midrule
Observations    & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} & \mc{459} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses.
\quad \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\).}\\

\end{tabular*}


\bigskip
\caption{Table B3\strut}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{d{2.6}} }
\toprule
&\mc{OLS}&\mc{0.1}&\mc{0.2}&\mc{0.4}&\mc{0.5}&\mc{0.6}&\mc{0.8}&\mc{0.9}\\
\midrule
dsentiment      &   -0.343\sym{***}&  -0.0907         &   -0.167         &   -0.271         &   -0.317\sym{*}  &   -0.364\sym{*}  &   -0.488\sym{***}&   -0.637\sym{**} \\
                & (0.0861)         &  (0.306)         &  (0.252)         &  (0.185)         &  (0.161)         &  (0.143)         &  (0.143)         &  (0.226)         \\
\addlinespace
dsubmissions    &    0.150\sym{***}&   0.0664         &   0.0917         &    0.126\sym{**} &    0.142\sym{***}&    0.157\sym{***}&    0.198\sym{***}&    0.248\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0190)         & (0.0693)         & (0.0571)         & (0.0420)         & (0.0366)         & (0.0327)         & (0.0332)         & (0.0537)         \\
\addlinespace
lag\_vol         &    0.886\sym{***}&    0.837\sym{***}&    0.852\sym{***}&    0.872\sym{***}&    0.882\sym{***}&    0.891\sym{***}&    0.915\sym{***}&    0.944\sym{***}\\
                & (0.0283)         &  (0.133)         &  (0.109)         & (0.0802)         & (0.0696)         & (0.0617)         & (0.0614)         & (0.0948)         \\
\addlinespace
stdev\_lag       &   -1.210\sym{***}&   -1.669         &   -1.531         &   -1.341         &   -1.256         &   -1.171         &   -0.944         &   -0.673         \\
                &  (0.346)         &  (2.238)         &  (1.837)         &  (1.346)         &  (1.168)         &  (1.036)         &  (1.028)         &  (1.582)         \\
\addlinespace
autocov         &    0.178\sym{***}&    0.211         &    0.201         &    0.187         &    0.181\sym{*}  &    0.175\sym{*}  &    0.159\sym{*}  &    0.140         \\
                & (0.0375)         &  (0.169)         &  (0.139)         &  (0.102)         & (0.0882)         & (0.0782)         & (0.0776)         &  (0.119)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant        &    2.273\sym{***} \\
                &  (0.537)          \\
\midrule
Observations    & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} & \mc{345} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses. 
\quad \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\).}\\

\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```